# How to get a segment of an Url

Tags: java, android-studio, url

I have an URL `https://example.com/A_segment/B_segment/ref=abc`. Is there a way to extract `B_segment` out of it?

*The URL is not always the same but B_segment always follow A_segment and ahead of ref=.

Comment: I think that adding output result would be useful!

Comment: Is there any pattern for what you want to extract?

Comment: Sorry but what's "adding output result". Thanks!

Comment: I want to extract product number out of amazon products' url

Comment: Answer depends on how you recognize that this is the part you want. For instance `B_segment` can be picked because it starts with `B_`. Would you also want to match it if it was in different location? Like for instance if it would be placed at `A_segment` position? OR do you want to get as result `B_segment` because it is after forth `/`? OR are there some other criteria that you are using to decide on result you want.

Comment: `new URI(s).getRawPath().split(Pattern.quote("/"))[2]`?

Comment: Thanks everyone@Pshemo and I would also want to match it if it was in different location, but B_segment always follows after A_segment and it's always ahead of /ref=

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question. Include rationale which you are using to decide/find correct result.

Comment: @Alt0216 if the answers are helpful for you, **click tick below number on the left side one of the answers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming URL can also be in form `http://server.domain/what/ever/A_segment/xxxx/ref=123` and that you are interested in `xxxx` part you can use regex to find part `/A_segment/(.+)/ref=`. Part `(.+)` represents one or more of any characters and because of parenthesis it will be placed in [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (here indexed as `1` since it is first (and only) group) to let us grab only match from that group.

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/STCyO4):

```
String url = "http://server.domain/what/ever/A_segment/xxxx/ref=123";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/A_segment/(.+)/ref=");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()){
    String result = m.group(1); //<-get match from group 1
    System.out.println(result); //Output: xxxx
} else {
    //here you can throw exception or return some default value in case of lack of match
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this work if the String url is not predefined but "String url = url.getUrl()"?

Comment: I am not sure what your `url` is (since none of standard Java classes like `URL` or `URI` doesn't have `getUrl()` method), but I don't see reasons why it shouldn't work if it returns String representing URL from similar to one from your question.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how can I add the result to another url? ex."https://another.exmaple/whatever"+result

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you mean. What you mean by "another url"? How is it different from url which you posted in question?

Comment: If the result is "12345", I want to use that and add to a new url "https://new.url/something/12345". I am sorry that my question is not clear.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean but I don't know what is the problem. `String anotherURL = "another.exmaple/whatever/"+result;` should work fine inside `if (m.find()){...}` section. Or is your question how to use that `result` variable outside of that `if`? In that case you can declare `String result = "";` somewhere before that `if`.